# Global Styles with React and Material UI

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm new to React and Material UI but I have to write an enterprise application with a nice styling. I would like to use some kind of global styles for my application (to be able to change it later on
) with functional components in react (maybe I will later add redux).

What's the best practice approach for global styles with react and material (latest versions)?

What about this one (`ThemeProvider`): https://material-ui.com/styles/advanced/?
I read about `MuiThemeProvider` but could not find it in the material version 4 documentation. Is it obsolete? What's the difference between MuiThemeProvider and `ThemeProvider`?

React (client-side rendering) & Material UI (latest versions)
Backend: Node

Comment: MuiThemeProvider was renamed to ThemeProvider in version 4, but [both names still work](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/v4.6.0/packages/material-ui/src/styles/index.js#L16).

Answer (score 16):

In Material UI v5, you can use [`GlobalStyles`](https://mui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#5-global-css-override) to do exactly that. From what I know, `GlobalStyles` is just a wrapper of emotion's [`Global`](https://emotion.sh/docs/globals) component. The usage is pretty straightforward:

```
import GlobalStyles from "@mui/material/GlobalStyles";
```

```
<GlobalStyles
  styles={{
    h1: { color: "red" },
    h2: { color: "green" },
    body: { backgroundColor: "lightpink" }
  }}
/>
```

Note that you don't even have to put it inside `ThemeProvider`, `GlobalStyles` uses the [`defaultTheme`](https://github.com/mui-org/material-ui/blob/a8eb649e47130bbde0058ae93895040719ac2012/packages/mui-material/src/GlobalStyles/GlobalStyles.js#L7) if not provided any:

```
return (
  <>
    <GlobalStyles
      styles={(theme) => ({
        h1: { color: theme.palette.primary.main },
        h2: { color: "green" },
        body: { backgroundColor: "lightpink" }
      })}
    />
    <h1>This is a h1 element</h1>
    <h2>This is a h2 element</h2>
  </>
);
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 58755118/global-styles-with-react-and-material-ui]

Comment: What is the correct type for the `theme` argument? I'm using the style in your latter example with TypeScript and am unable to type it correctly. Works with `any`, however.

Comment: What is the best way for implementing css lines such as... `input[type='text']:focus {outline: none;}`, `* {box-sizing: border-box;}`, `*::before {box-sizing: border-box;}`, `*::after {box-sizing: border-box;}`

Answer (score 15):

You can actually write global styles with material UI:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    '@global': {
        '.MuiPickersSlideTransition-transitionContainer.MuiPickersCalendarHeader-transitionContainer': {
            order: -1,
        },
        '.MuiTypography-root.MuiTypography-body1.MuiTypography-alignCenter': {
            fontWeight: 'bold',
        }
    }
}));
```

Answer (score 11):

**Global Styles with Material UI & React**

```
// 1. GlobalStyles.js
import { createStyles, makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core';

const useStyles = makeStyles(() =>
  createStyles({
    '@global': {
      html: {
        '-webkit-font-smoothing': 'antialiased',
        '-moz-osx-font-smoothing': 'grayscale',
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%'
      },
      '*, *::before, *::after': {
        boxSizing: 'inherit'
      },
      body: {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%'
      },
      '#root': {
        height: '100%',
        width: '100%'
      }
    }
  })
);

const GlobalStyles = () => {
  useStyles();

  return null;
};

export default GlobalStyles;
```

** Then Use it in App.js like below**

```
// 2. App.js
import React from 'react';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import { Router } from 'react-router-dom';

import { NavBar, Routes, GlobalStyles, Routes } from '../';

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: 'blue'
    }
  }
});

const App = () => {
  return (
    <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <Router>
        <NavBar />
        <GlobalStyles />
        <Routes />
      </Router>
    </MuiThemeProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

**This Works for me with my react project.**

Comment: Personally, I'd rather rename the `useStyles` to `useGlobalStyles`, and then call it right in the `App` component. The `GlobalStyles` component, to me, feels like a layer of indirection that doesn't provide any benefits.

Both work, it's just a choice of preference.

Answer (score 7):

For global styles you can use it like shown below.
This is the best implementation that has worked for me.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      '@global': {
        html: {
          WebkitFontSmoothing: 'auto',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});

// ...
return (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <CssBaseline />
    {children}
  </ThemeProvider>
);
```

For more reference: [Global CSS](https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/#global-css)

Answer (score 3):

In my experience, using MuiThemeProvider and createMuiTheme have worked wonderfully. However, I am using Material-UI version 3.9.2.

MuiThemeProvider should wrap around your entire application. All you need to do in all of your components would be to instead of passing your styles object to with styles, pass a function that passes in the theme.

Ex:

```
import React from 'react';
import { MuiThemeProvider, createMuiTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import {NavBar, Routes} from '../'
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    primary: {
      main: 'red'
    },
  },
/* whatever else you want to add here */
});

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
        <NavBar />
        <Routes />
      </MuiThemeProvider>
    )
  }
```

then in navbar let's say:

```
import React from 'react';
import { withStyles } from '@material-ui/core';
const styles = theme => ({
  root: {
    color: theme.palette.primary.main,,
  }
})

const NavBar = ({classes}) => {
  return <div className={classes.root}>navigation</div>
}

export default withStyles(styles)(NavBar);
```

Hope that helps, works very well for me!