# How to style body element in Material UI

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, themes

I can't find any way to target root elements with the `ThemeProvider` from Material UI.

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  palette: {
    background: {
      default: "#00000",
      backgroundColor : 'black',
      backgroundImage: 'url(/bg.jpg)',
      backgroundPosition: 'center',
      height:'100%'
    },
    primary: {
      light: '#757ce8',
      main: '#fff',
      dark: '#002884',
      contrastText: 'grey',
    },
  },
});
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

#### Material UI v5

You can change the body styles by overriding [`MuiCssBaseline`](https://next.material-ui.com/components/css-baseline/#scrollbars) styles in `createTheme()`:

```
import CssBaseline from "@mui/material/CssBaseline";
import darkScrollbar from "@mui/material/darkScrollbar";
import { createTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@mui/material/styles";

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      styleOverrides: {
        body: {
          ...darkScrollbar(),
          color: "darkred",
          backgroundColor: "grey",
          "& h1": {
            color: "black"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

export default function GlobalCssOverride() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <Content />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit GlobalCssOverride Material Demo (forked)]

#### Material UI v4

You can apply the styles to the `body` using [`@global class`](https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/#global-css) like this:

```js
const useGlobalStyles = makeStyles({
  "@global": {
    body: {
      backgroundColor: "tomato"
    }
  }
});
const theme = createMuiTheme({});

function MyThemeProvider({ children }) {
  useGlobalStyles();
  return <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>{children}</ThemeProvider>;
}

function App() {
  return (
    <MyThemeProvider>
      <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
        Button
      </Button>
    </MyThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

If you create the project by `create-react-app`, you can also use css/scss module to style any element globally:

```css
/* styles.css */
body {
  color: white;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```js
import React from "react";
import Button from "@material-ui/core/Button";
import "./styles.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <Button variant="contained" color="primary">
      Hello World
    </Button>
  );
}
```

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 64705335/how-to-style-body-element-in-materialui]

Comment: How to change a part of dark mode ? this solution works from 1 theme , what if i want to have 2 ? and modify part of one of those themes ?

Comment: @Richardson, check out this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59838973/merge-theme-configuration-settings-in-material-ui
It shows you how to create a separate object for `ThemeOptions`, which can be shared between multiple themes. That might be what you're looking for

Answer (score 3):

Another approach outlined in the [**Docs > Themes > Globals**](https://material-ui.com/customization/globals/#global-css) section:

> If you are using the [`CssBaseline`](https://material-ui.com/components/css-baseline/) component to apply global resets, it can also be used to apply global styles.

Here's an example:

```
import { createMuiTheme, ThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      "@global": {
        body: {
          backgroundColor: "tomato"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

#### [Demo in CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-ui-global-styles-xm4p9) and Stack Snippets

```js
const { ThemeProvider, createMuiTheme, CssBaseline } = MaterialUI

const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      "@global": {
        body: {
          backgroundColor: "tomato",
        },
      },
    },
  },
})

const App = () => {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@material-ui/core@latest/umd/material-ui.production.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```

#### Update for MUI 5

Create your theme like this:

```
import { createTheme } from "@mui/material";

export const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      styleOverrides: {
        body: {
          backgroundColor: "tomato"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

**Further Reading**: [Global Styles with React and Material UI](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58755118/1366033)

Comment: This approach is better than the other one +1.

Answer (score 1):

#### In **Material-UI v5** there are two ways to do this:

With the `GlobalStyles` component:

```
import * as React from 'react';
import GlobalStyles from '@material-ui/core/GlobalStyles';

export default function App() {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <GlobalStyles styles={{ h1: { color: 'grey' } }} />
      <h1>Grey h1 element</h1>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Edit on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nwotn?file=/demo.js)

---

Or if you are already using the `CssBaseline` component for setting baseline styles:

```
import { ThemeProvider, createTheme } from '@material-ui/core/styles';

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MuiCssBaseline: {
      styleOverrides: `
        h1 {
          color: grey;
        }
      `,
    },
  },
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <CssBaseline />
      <h1>Grey h1 element</h1>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Edit on [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/y2z5u?file=/demo.js)

---

From the official docs: [Global CSS Override](https://next.material-ui.com/customization/how-to-customize/#5-global-css-override)